# Pass data between extended components OR call method of component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs2

I have main component which fetch list of users in `Created()` method. Two next components extended of main component. In this case created method calls each time at extended components created. So i have extra call of fetch list of users. Goal is fetch users one time and pass it to extended components.

For example:

> https://jsfiddle.net/apokjqxx/45/

In example we can see that `Created()` method of main components called two time but need one time and pass data to extended components. What's best solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Each extended component is a different object instance, that's why `Created()` and fetch are been executed twice.

What you need is another piece of code acting like a storage (cache) for your item's list, this piece of code should be instantiated once and shared among your components.

[Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/) is probably a good option for that "piece of code"

Comment: I thought about a storage and another piece of code. Maybe use props... Vuex is good but I'll want to  try  solve it via clear VueJs . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your `math` and `physics` component share the same data, and even have a lot in common in template, why not make them one component? This will solve your duplicated fetch issue, and you can easily rearrange your template by wrapping your current template with a `v-for` and use

```
data() {
    return {
        lists: [
            {course: 'math', people: ['mike', 'arnold', 'tony']},
            {course: 'physics', people: ['mike', 'arnold', 'tony']}
        ]
    };
}
```

as your data.

Comment: I need different components to use different logic with users. Also for each components will used custom templates in Tabs.

Comment: Your example little incorrect. I have list(10k) of users and they should be separated by courses and for each course should be created template. Thanks

Comment: @user3816475 Not totally clear about your situation, but you may try [slot](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#slot) to enable the parent component to insert custom templates in the child's predefined position.

Comment: So main goal is get default data and use it in any components. So i have list of users, settings of current page in DB. And i want to get them in any components of VueJs.

Comment: @user3816475 You can try out [global event bus](http://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication) to do this without vuex.